Dynamic Library Import for Maps JavaScript API not working in Apps script
I'm trying to switch to the Dynamic Library Import API (from the outdated script tag). I made an example according to the documentation in a Google spreadsheet on Apps Script. As a result, I expect to get a Google map in the browser, but I get an error in the console

userCodeAppPanel:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input userCodeAppPanel:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importLibrary') at initMap (userCodeAppPanel:6:39) at userCodeAppPanel:15:1

Below is the code from Apps script:
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script>
let map; 
// initMap is now async
async function initMap() { 
    // Request libraries when needed, not in the script tag.
    const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    // Short namespaces can be used.
    map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 40.72476, lng: -74.04843 },
        zoom: 8,
    });

}

initMap();
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  
   <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src="https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?"+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg", v: "weekly"});</script>

<style>
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
</style>
  </body>
</html>

But the same code in jsfiddle is processed without errors (the result is displayed as a map).
I assume that something is missing in Apps Script. Please help me understand the reason and run the code on Dynamic Library Import
Update:
Fixing the quotes partially solved the problem (Thanks Tanaike).
Now the error remains:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
(reading 'importLibrary')

To reproduce the error, you can use a Google spreadsheet with a modal window call. First, press F12 to display the console in the browser, then the script button and open the map

Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue in  the question itself (not just links to external resources).

I wrote an example of an error in the browser console. Now this is my problem.
I also wrote the code that causes the error in the console.
You can reproduce the code in Apps scripts (in the table at the link or yours).
I have read your link, but please clarify how else can I provide an example of the error and code?

Solutions or announcements that a problem should not be posted in the question body. Instead, consider accepting the answer that helps you most and/or posting your solution as an answer. Ref. What should I do when someone answers my question? and Can I answer my own question?

"You have only shared an HTML file and not shown the Apps Script code that would load that HTML" - The script code is written inside the ntml code. The deployment is done on the application Apps script platform. Sorry, I have specified everything in the link and I have nothing to add.

When I saw your showing script, I remembered this issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156139610 In the current stage, when Javascript is written in an HTML file with the script editor of Google Apps Script, when // is included in the template literal, it seems that this line is used as a comment line. In your script, at a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e, // is used. By this, the script after // is used as a comment. I guessed that this issue might be the reason for your current issue.
In order to remove this issue, please modify it as follows.
From:
a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e

To:
a.src=`https:\/\/maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e

When you modify the script of Web Apps, please reflect the latest script to Web Apps. Please be careful about this.
Note:

By the way, after you modify the above modification when another error RefererNotAllowedMapError occurs, please check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error.

The current URL loading the Maps JavaScript API has not been added to the list of allowed referrers. Please check the referrer settings of your API key in the Cloud Console.



Reference:

Google Issue Tracker: When // in template literal is used in a HTML file in script editor, it is used as a comment start.

Added:
How about the following modification?
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: grey;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
  (g => { var h, a, k, p = "The Google Maps JavaScript API", c = "google", l = "importLibrary", q = "__ib__", m = document, b = window; b = b[c] || (b[c] = {}); var d = b.maps || (b.maps = {}), r = new Set, e = new URLSearchParams, u = () => h || (h = new Promise(async (f, n) => { await (a = m.createElement("script")); e.set("libraries", [...r] + ""); for (k in g) e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, t => "_" + t[0].toLowerCase()), g[k]); e.set("callback", c + ".maps." + q); a.src = `https:\/\/maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` + e; d[q] = f; a.onerror = () => h = n(Error(p + " could not load.")); a.nonce = m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce || ""; m.head.append(a) })); d[l] ? console.warn(p + " only loads once. Ignoring:", g) : d[l] = (f, ...n) => r.add(f) && u().then(() => d[l](f, ...n)) })
    ({ key: "AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg", v: "weekly" });
  </script>

  <script>
  let map;
  console.log('let map');

  async function initMap() {
    console.log('start initMap');
    // Request libraries when needed, not in the script tag.
    const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    // Short namespaces can be used.

    map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: { lat: 50.397, lng: -70.644 },
      zoom: 4
    });
  }

  initMap();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>


Thank you for your comment. Correcting the quotation mark helped to remove the syntax error.
Now the error remains: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importLibrary')

@Volodymyr Thank you for replying. From Thank you for your comment. Correcting the quotation mark helped to remove the syntax error., I underestood that your initial issue was resolved. About your new issue Now the error remains: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importLibrary'), I added the whole modified script. Please confirm it.

Tanaike thank you! Your solution helped. Now I can move on. I have added your solution to the original question.

@Volodymyr Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
